# AngularJS Ошибка в функции?

Tags: angularjs

Обращение к функции:

```
   $scope.record = function(rid) {
                    $http.get('http://syncmobile.com/device/record/'+rid)
                        .then(function success(response) {
                            console.log(response.data);
                            $scope.records = response.data;
                        }, function error(err) {
                            console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
                        });
                };
```

возвращает:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["filename"]=>
    string(34) "f76ddd.pic"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["filename"]=>
    string(34) "c7ebb.mp3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["filename"]=>
    string(34) "ba55dc.pic"
  }
}
```

Думаю, что в функции допущены ошибки. Помогите вывести содержимое `filename` ?

Comment: Что-то по-моему ты вместо json'а какую-то php'шную муть шлёшь...

Comment: Обработчик: $app->get('/device/record/[{rid}]', function($request, $response, $rid) {
    $record = \Models\Loading::select('filename')->where('rid', $rid)->get()->toArray();

    foreach($record as $file){
        $arr[] = array('filename' => $file["filename"]);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
});